# Flight visualization in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, google-earth, viewshed, altitude

In the CSV file I have accurate data on location, altitude, and time. In Google Earth point by point I manage to create the following visualization,
[image]

is it possible to create the same visualization in QGIS?

Comment: I think it's kind of possible with the 3D view in QGIS or the Qgis2threejs plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I see, the solution by @bugmenot123 does not work as intended: native Qgis 3D symbology accepts only a fixed valued for the elevation, no data driven override to use the values of an elevation attribute.

So you have to stick to  qgis2threejs plugin, but there, you can only use the pre-defined symbols and combining point + line does not seem to be possible.

What works, however, is to use object type cylinder, where for the hight you can use an attribute value for elevation: right click the layer containing the elevation information, set Object type to Cylinder and set Height to the attribute field containing the elevation information. This can be seen using a real world example of a GPS file, recorded on a plane starting from Istanbul:

[image]

Using `Box` Style:

[image]

Filtering features (show only features with id>76) and stlying the color with Viridis color ramp using the expression `ramp_color( 'Viridis', abs (1-scale_linear (ele, 0, 4500, 0,1)))`

[image]

Using a DEM, be sure that for `Z-Coordinate / Altitude` you select `Expression` (not `Z value`) and set it to 0 / leave it empty so that the symbols are connected to the ground, see:
[image]

However, be sure what kind of measurements you have: elevation above ground? Then stick to this solution. Or do you rather have geoid height/height above see level? Then better use `Absolute` Mode for `Z coordinate`. If I use my real world GPS-measurements from the plane, using the Reltive to the ground option, the plane seems to go up and down, based on the topography. This was probably not the case, it had a more or less constant height above the geoid:

*Plane moving up and down, based on the topography (valleys, mountains) - this does probably not visualize the real trajectory of the plane. For visualization purpose, I scaled the elevation to 10% of its actual value, but the principle remains the same:*
[image]

Same scene, but with `Z coordinate` set to `Absolute` - a more realistic picture of a more or less constant hight above see level:
[image]

*Looking to this last solution from underneath: all cylinders start at the same level and reach Earth's surface at varying distanes, depending on topography/relief:*
[image]

Comment: I managed to do it but the cylinders and the boxes do not start from zero. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w3NM6Y4Lzl8L7cfd8anpzXZuY0o-KNyi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Realitive to "BG" layer, where "BG" layer is my DEM layer.

Comment: For `Z-Coordinate / Altitude`, select `Expression` (not `Z value`) and set it to 0

Comment: Yes, it's now OK. Thank you!!!

Comment: qgis2threejs takes the style from the layer, no need for an expression there :)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. You have two options, the native QGIS 3D view or the [qgis2threejs](https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs) plugin.

For qgis2threejs you can select a DEM as background, drape a texture on it as you like (from the canvas or a layer or else). Then visualise the points as a 3D object located in 3D space by using their 2D geographic information and the altitude as offset above the ground level. For the lines you could duplicate the points layer and use a thin line 3D object.

Make sure you are using a projected coordinate system on the canvas before opening the qgis2threejs editor or elevation will look broken.

Make sure you save the imported data in a proper geospatial format like GeoPackage or Shapefile or generating the 3D scene will be extra slow.

Consider turning the point data into 3D geometries using QGIS' processing tools, then qgis2three would automatically use the Z component from them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how you can use 3D objects to be visualized in the desired way. Did you test it? You can use the built in symbology of qgis2threejs plugin, but not the native QGIS 3D symbols, as there, you can't use any attribute values for hight, you have to enter a fixed value. And for qgis2threejs, you can add only one symbol like a cylinder - but not point plus line. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I only described the qgis2threejs because QGIS 3D is still not usable to me. For point plus line just duplicate the layer in the main QGIS window first and use one for the line, the other for the point. Alternatively one could abuse labels with a point character and the leader lines serving as vertical lines.