# Creating elevation profile from points with X,Y,Z coordinates

Tags: qgis, point, elevation, plot

I have a set of points that contain X, Y and Z data. I am trying to plot these either in 3d space or 2d space using X and Z. As an extra it would be nice to be able to compare different sets of data and measure between points as well.

I can't figure out a way to do this with QGIS. I have tried using the elevation tool however it only works with a line and requires a raster file I believe.

Sorry for been unclear. For some clarity:

Yes i can view it in 2d but i would like to either view it in 2d but with the x and z axis (opposed to the x and y axis normally shown in the 2d view) or in a 3d space which would be ideal.

By compare i mean add two sets of data to the one plot (either 2d or 3d) so i can visually see the difference between the two sets of data. Also been able to measure between point in the z axis would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jim, welcome to GIS SE. Sorry, your question is unclear: you have a point layer - so what do you mean by "to plot these "? If you have points, they should already appear in 2d on your map canvas? So your question is about 3d only? And what exactly do you mean by "compare different sets of data and measure between points as well"? As long as you don't make clear what exactly you have and what you want to achieve, it's impossible to help. Please try avoiding the question being closed, hit the `Edit` button and revise your question, adding details and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: See here for how to visualize points in 3d, if that was the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422385/88814

Comment: I would add that in the next release of QGIS 3.26, coming soon, the 3D viewer has been improved, such that it accepts and displays in 3D a CSV file with Z values in a column as you describe. Creating a profile is then trivial.  See the coming features in this QGIS open day webinar:  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-ZMRpk0mv8

Comment: Thanks Babel and Micha, i will look into the qgis2threejs plugin and also the update that should be out any day soon.   Thanks for your help!